# Can i use "Remote Disc" from a Linux host remotely to OS X?

Tags: macos, unix

I just got my first MacBook Pro (retina), so I'm new to OS X. It does not have an optical drive, but I notice there's a "Remote Disc" device in Finder.

I was wondering if I can mount my physical disc from another Linux machine on the network and have it appear as a "Remote Disc" on MacBook Pro. Is this possible?

I have been using sshfs to connect Linux directories to OS X, but I wanted to access Audio discs as well, and those cannot be mounted through sshfs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely no because it's proprietary technology.

Apple's remote disc functionality is provided by the host OS which has to be OS X or Windows having the proper drivers installed. You also have to have a fairly current Mac which has no built-in optical drive.

Have a look at Apple's knowledge base for a more detailed explanation: [DVD or CD sharing: Using Remote Disc](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5287)

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. Wanted to award the +50 bounty...but was told to wait 24hours... so let's wait. Cheers!

Comment: @kctang Don't forget to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rip the audio discs on Linux using ffmpeg/mencoder/etc and then share those files to your Mac using Samba.  A little less direct than you were hoping for, but perfectly viable.

If you want to share data discs, you can do the same by mounting the discs in the Linux filesystem and then sharing those mount points (again, using Samba).  That's how I do it.